# Function not invoking in Shopify Slate Template JS file

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am using Slate V1.* to develop a Shopify Theme. I have a js file for a specific template:

collection.bundle-product.js

```
// Get bundle total cost
function getTotal(data) {

  var total = 0;
  var products = [];

  data.forEach(function (item) {
    products.push({ price: item.price });
  });

  products.forEach(function (product) {
    total += product.price;
  });

  return total;
};
```

I am trying to call the getTotal function from within the collection.bundle-product.liquid template file:

```
(function () {
    var bundleValue = getTotal(productCollection);
})();
```

I am getting the following console error:
    Uncaught ReferenceError: getTotal is not defined

I can confirm the JS file is loaded correctly. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm if you load your JS in the `<head>` section or at the end of the `<body>` tag. If it's the second you don't have access to that function yet and it returns undefined.

Comment: I have called the function inside document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){ ... }); and can confirm the JS file is loaded first and I still don't have access to the function.

Comment: Are you adding the `collection.bundle-product.js` in a separate script or you are importing it in the main bundle.js of slate? I don't remember if slate bundle.js scope was global or it was wrapped in a self invoking anonymous function rendering all functions local for that file only and not accessible outside of it.

Comment: It's a separate file. But I think you might be right about the scope and build process that slate performs on the js files. Defer tag on the script tag is also not helping, which slate seems to add on deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the way JS is bundled with Slate/Webpack the functions have no global scope. So I have attached it to the window object like so:

```
window.themeBundles = {
  getTotal(data) {

    var total = 0;
    var products = [];

    data.forEach(function (item) {
      products.push({ price: item.price });
    });

    products.forEach(function (product) {
      total += product.price;
    });

    return total;
  }
}
```

I can then call it from a liquid template file like so:

```
themeBundles.getTotal(productCollection)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is getting executed before the js file loads. What you can do is wait for the function to be available and then execute the function.

```
findTotal = function(){
  if(typeof(getTotal)!='function'){
    console.log('getTotal not found');
    setTimeout(findTotal, 50);
  }
  else{
    console.log('getTotal function found');
    bundleValue = getTotal(productCollection);
};
```